# Finding Z-Value from Percentile

Tags: standard-deviation

So I am just starting to work with standard distribution and deviation. I was wondering how to find the z-value of a percent. For example: Which z-value corresponds to the bottom 10% of standard distribution?

Answer (score 0):

There is a table showing the z-values, and what percent corresponds with which z-value : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAVX2.png)

I know this, but is there any way to actually solve for z values?